# C# set April 1st as start of year

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on an app to add data to a SQL table.

One of the fields in the table is for financial month as YYYYMM (e.g. 201805 for August 2018). I need to set this automatically when the row is added as we can't rely on the users to input the correct format.

Is there any way to set DateTime to start the year on 1st April (first day of financial year), or am I going to have to code my way around the issue.

Comment: I guess you could implement your own Calendar

Comment: You could do that with a trigger or constraint on the table i suppose.

Comment: I would implement you own calendar or add the difference between JAN 1 and APR 1 before storing data in the DB or as getting out of it. Your own implementation would make the most sense though.

Comment: Just code around the issue.  e.g save the dates normally, and just add 4 months and 1 day

Comment: This is likely to be purely a presentation issue. So, use the normal calendar for you culture in the database and code, and only when you come to present the data (in the UI, to other systems, in reports etc) do the necessary conversion. Similarly on input, convert from financial format to the usual format for your culture.

Comment: This is not straight-forward at all.  You'll get in trouble on July 31st for example.  By your rule that would be month number 4, but April only has 30 days.  So this can't be a DateTime.  Storing strings in a dbase to represent dates is, well, ugh.   This ought to be done only at the last possible moment, just before a human sees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, they did help me solve the problem.

I eventually went with a really simple solution that I probably should have thought of in the first place.

```
string period = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString("yyyyMM");
```

Comment: If they did help you solve the problem, you might consider upvoting them

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following piece of code to get the start of your desired financial year.

```
    var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    DateTime firstDay;
    if(DateTime.Now.Month <= 4)
       firstDay = new DateTime(year-1, 4, 1);
    else
       firstDay = new DateTime(year, 4, 1);
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this automatically, but it looks simple enough.

Comment: Except that would use the same financial year for March 1st and May 1st, which isn't what the OP would want, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a varchar (or nvarchar) column, with a default that looks something like:

```
     (format(dateadd(month,(-4),getdate()),''yyyyMM'',''en-US''))
```

But, it appears that SQL Server doesn't like having a default with three functions nested inside each other (two, it seems ok with, but it burps on three).  Instead, you can have a `Date` type column with a default of:

```
     (dateadd(month,(-4),getdate()))
```

That seems to work, but it's a date 4 months ago.  Then just format it correctly whenever you display it.